# jQuery replace string after specific character

Tags: javascript, jquery

String:

> https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/501738/13_english.png?968921

After replace:

> https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/501738/13_english.png?12345

```js
var url = 'https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/501738/13_english.png?968921';
url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?'));
console.log(url)
```

My function is helping in removing string but not helpful for replacing string How can I solve this?

Comment: If you have the string without the bit you don't want on the end, you could always just add it...? `url = url + "?12345";` Though it would help if you could give some context, do you just want the string? Are you changing the actual URL? will this be used on multiple pages or a single exact string match?

Answer (score 0):

try jquery string replace function:

```
var string = "https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/501738/13_english.png?968921";
string = string.replace("968921", "12345");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just add your new number at the end of your string since you already have the functionality of removing the old one.

```js
var url = 'https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/501738/13_english.png?968921';
url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('?') + 1) + "12345";
console.log(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

A way without static numbers

```js
let x = 'https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/501738/13_english.png?968921',
  y = x.substr(0, x.indexOf('?'), x.length - x.indexOf('?')) + '?' + '2222222'
console.log(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about splitting the URL and replacing the second part with your required string.

```js
var url = 'https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/501738/13_english.png?968921';

console.log(url.replace(url.split('?')[1],"12345"))
```